# Google Maps Android API: How to limit the camera of a map to specific bounds?

Tags: android, google-maps, camera, bounds

I want to limit the camera of a Google Map (Google Maps Android API v2) to a specific area (described as latlng bounds).

I know that I can limit the movement of the camera with: `setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget(bounds)`. But this only affects the center of the camera. The user can still move to the edge of the map, such that the edge of the map is in the center of the view.

Do you know how to avoid this behavior?

Comment: Yes you can do it by disabling gesture.

Comment: Yes you are right, but then you can not scroll and zoom in the map.

Comment: See [this](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory&method=newLatLngBounds)

Comment: Its a nice link - but I'm not sure if these examples solve my problem.